# Bootstrap CSS and JS do I have to include them in seperate files or can compile them?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering with Bootstrap CSS and JS

in my  do I have to list them as seperate files i.e.

```
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

and then lets say I have my custom CSS and JS file

```
<script src="custom.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom/.css" />
```

To make it easier on other people to get a particular javascript control up and running and including 4 files, can I join the bootstrap JS and CSS with my custom JS and CSS into a single CSS & JS file ofcourse keeping the copyright information etc from bootstrap.

Or does legally bootstrap require to be listed seperately ?

Comment: It is good practice to keep Bootstrap's CSS and JS separate from your own. An example is Bootstrap's theme they allow you to download, which is a separate CSS file that adds to Bootstrap's default.

Comment: Is your question about combining the files or license?

Comment: Combining my files for production

Comment: You could leave them as separate, and then if you're using Wordpress or a CMS, use an SEO plugin to combine all your CSS and JS files into one file if you want to make it as streamlined as possible

Comment: [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) may be something you're looking for. You include on JS file and it includes all your files for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, its OK. Whether its the best method or not is a whole other subject.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#license-faqs

> License FAQs
>
> Bootstrap is released under the MIT license and is copyright 2015
> Twitter. Boiled down to smaller chunks, it can be described with the
> following conditions.
>
> It requires you to: Keep the license and copyright notice included in
> Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript files when you use them in your works
>
> It permits you to: Freely download and use Bootstrap, in whole or in
> part, for personal, private, company internal, or commercial purposes
> Use Bootstrap in packages or distributions that you create Modify the
> source code Grant a sublicense to modify and distribute Bootstrap to
> third parties not included in the license
>
> It forbids you to: Hold the
> authors and license owners liable for damages as Bootstrap is provided
> without warranty Hold the creators or copyright holders of Bootstrap
> liable Redistribute any piece of Bootstrap without proper attribution
> Use any marks owned by Twitter in any way that might state or imply
> that Twitter endorses your distribution Use any marks owned by Twitter
> in any way that might state or imply that you created the Twitter
> software in question
>
> It does not require you to: Include the source of
> Bootstrap itself, or of any modifications you may have made to it, in
> any redistribution you may assemble that includes it Submit changes
> that you make to Bootstrap back to the Bootstrap project (though such
> feedback is encouraged) The full Bootstrap license is located in the
> project repository for more information.

Comment: Well both I guess, I know it will work but I guess I was wondering is it allowed or will I run into trouble doing it this way

Answer (score 0):

You can but make sure the order is the same as they were separate files.